# Kohana - comments under article

Tags: comments, kohana, hmvc, article

How to show comments under the article in Kohana v3.2 ? Should I use subrequest to Comments Controller or just call the Comment model in "View" action of Article controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id preffer to HMVC calls. With HMVC you can use the same code for internal subrequests (show comment list under the article) and external calls (load/reload comments via AJAX)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple pieces at play here.  How do you get comment data to your views to use in multiple pages...well maybe create a model that does the comment retrieving.

How do you format the comments the same across multiple pages?  You can either use a custom helper to format it into some standard html or you can do the view within a view logic to load the comment fragment in into the page.